# How to get specific values from all UserID (UID) and save in RecyclerViewFirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, kotlin-android-extensions

How can I get the UID from all users from my database with the structure below and save it in my FirebaseRecyclerviewUI? I have tried for several hours but my recycler view still displays null.

```
-User
 |
  -uid
   |
    -advert
     |
      -bus_name
      -category
      -purl
      -id
```

[image]

Below is my getter/setter BusinessListData class that serves as the model for receiving the values and sending them to recyclerview

```
class BusinessListData {

    var id: String = ""

    var propixurl: String = ""

    var business_name: String = ""
    var category: String = ""

    constructor(){

    }

    constructor(id: String, propixurl: String, business_name: String, category: String) {
        this.id = id

        this.propixurl = propixurl
        this.business_name = business_name
        this.category = category
    }

    fun getID(): String{
        return id
    }
    fun getUrl(): String{
        return propixurl
    }
    fun getBusName(): String{
        return business_name
    }

    fun getCate(): String{
        return category
    }

    fun setID(id: String){
        this.id = id
    }
    fun setUrl(propixurl: String){
        this.propixurl = propixurl
    }
    fun setBusName(business_name: String){
        this.business_name = business_name
    }
    fun setCate(category: String){
        this.category = category
    }
}
```

My FirebaseRecyclerViewUI details are below. The mDatabase is the reference to the database and I tried getting the snapshot of the data which was successful according to my Log.v values. The problem is that I could not get the specific values under the Advert tree in my Firebase RealTime Database

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BusinessListData> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BusinessListData>()
    .setQuery(mDatabase, object: SnapshotParser<BusinessListData> {

        override fun parseSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot): BusinessListData {
                Log.v("snapshotfire", snapshot.toString()) //returns all snapshot values
                Log.v("snapshotfire", snapshot.child("purl").toString()) // this returns null
                Log.v("snapshotfire", snapshot.child("bus_name").getValue().toString()) //this also returns null

            return BusinessListData(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("purl").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("bus_name").getValue().toString(),
                snapshot.child("category").getValue().toString()
            )
        }

    })
    .build()
```

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a certain query or database reference to the FirebaseUI adapters, it will show each child node of that reference/query. Since you pass in the root of your database, your `parseSnapshot` will be called for each child node of the root, which does not seem to be what you want.

To show the child nodes of the `User` node, pass in a reference to *that* node:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BusinessListData> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BusinessListData>()
    .setQuery(mDatabase.child("User"), object: SnapshotParser<BusinessListData> {
        ...
```

Now your `parseSnapshot` will be called for each child node of `User`, and you can get the necessary keys/values from that snapshot.

For example, to get the UID you can either read the snapshot's key or its `advert/uid` property:

```
override fun parseSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot): BusinessListData {
    Log.v("snapshotfire", snapshot.key)
    Log.v("snapshotfire", snapshot.child("advert/id").getValue())
)
```

Comment: What does "It still return null values" mean? Can you show the `null` values in code, instead of describing it?